# joining coefficient names from two different models in R

Tags: r, names

I have the following names from a model:

```
names(M1$coefficients)
"X1"   "X2"   "X3"
names(M2$coefficients)
"Z1"   "Z2"
```

I would like to append these two names into a single one so that at the end I get:

```
"X1"   "X2"   "X3"   "Z1"   "Z2"
```

I tried putting both into a list but I get the following which doesn't work for what I want.

```
[[1]]
[1] "X1"   "X2"   "X3"    
[[2]]
[1] "Z1"   "Z2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple `append` the two lists together:

```
append(names(M1$coefficients),names(M2$coefficients))
```

yielding

```
[1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "Z1" "Z2"
```

Comment: I think `?c` is more suitable here (at least less typing)